# When using Apple Hosted Content with In app purchase on iOS, is it possible to download the content before buying?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, in-app-purchase, iap-hosted-content

I am working on an app that is going to use IAP with Apple hosted content. I want to show images of the content to the people that are downloading it before they buy. Is it possible for the app to download the content from Apples server before user has purchased it? That way i could load images from that package and show them. And when user buys it, the app shows the rest of the content in the package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To start a download you must use startDownloads: on SKPaymnetQueue, and for that you need the user to click on the buy button, so it's not possible to start a download from itunes hosted content without buying. In addition even if it's possible the full content would be downloaded, so you will need code to unlock it depending on the purchase and your app will consume user resources for nothing.

From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentQueue_Class/Reference/Reference.html), I understand that you cannot reach the startDonwloads: without validating the purchase.

I think the best aproach would be providing the preview from your own server.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot download the hosted content before it is purchased. Best option is to display a preview of the product, either bundled in your app or downloaded from your own server.